# How can I insert the result of store procedure in available table in my sql server?

Tags: sql-server-2016

I need to save the result of my store procedure in the defined table in my sql server. I test different code for that ,but, non of them was useful.
Could you please hep me?
This is my code:

```
AS BEGIN EXEC sp_execute_external_script    @language =N'R',       @script=N'   library(e1071);   naivemodel <-naiveBayes(datafile[,3:12], datafile[,13]);   trained_model <- data.frame(payload = as.raw(serialize(naivemodel, connection=NULL)));
      ',  
      @input_data_1 =N'SELECT * from R_CT',    @input_data_1_name = N'datafile',   @output_data_1_name = N'trained_model'   with result sets ((model varbinary(max)));       end; insert into my_models (model) exec sp_RDA_Prd_naiveBayes; update my_models set model_name = 'e1071 - Naive Bayes' where model_name = 'default model'; select * from my_models;
```

but,I confronted with this error:

*Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition.*

This is the defined table:

```
create table my_models (
    model_name varchar(30) not null default('default model') primary key,
    model varbinary(max) not null
);
```

Comment: Simple, the error suggest that you are using wrong number of arguments or wrong argument types. Let take a closer look at your table my_models , 1st argument is varchar(30), 2nd argement is varbinary(max). But your code is "insert into my_models (model)"

Comment: Yes, but I have default value for this field. as you can see, I use "default('default model')" for that. It is not enough?

Comment: No it is not enough. You see ,how can the Insertion know that your model-> model_name or model-> model ? At least you should have a look at Insertion syntax in MySQL. INSERT INTO TABLE_NAME (column1, column2, column3,...columnN)  
VALUES (value1, value2, value3,...valueN);

Comment: This is not a normal insert query. I used this command: INSERT INTO Table
Exec [sp] for returning the value of store procedure as a VALUE. if I use  "INSERT INTO TABLE_NAME (column1, column2, column3,...columnN) VALUES (value1, value2, value3,...valueN);"  The result of SP could not be recognized! I try it before.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest

```
INSERT INTO my_models (model) VALUES (model)
```

the first 'model' is you column name,the second 'model' is your actual value

Comment: I used INSERT INTO my_models (model) VALUES (model); BUT, I confronted with this error: Invalid column name 'model'. It couldn't recognize the model (The result of SP) as a VALUE.

Comment: then try INSERT INTO my_models (model_name, model) VALUES ('test', model)...But be careful as you set model_name to be primary key . At least you should have some hand on testings